# How can I prove the relation between ds and dA works in this surface area formula? (quick)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, area, surfaces, surface-integrals

Basically, I'm stuck in this exercise for 2 hours and the manual doesn't give the answer, plus it seems like a easy one, but I can't get it.
So basically I have to demonstrate that:
$$Area(S)=\int \int_D \frac{dA}{|cos\phi|}$$
where $$\phi$$is
is the angle between the normal unit vector of the surface and the vertical which is the unit vector $$k$$
So from the formula I have in my books for area of a surface, is $$ Area(S)=\int \int_D ds =\int \int_D ||ru \times rv|| dA$$
And my idea is that $$n\cdot k = |n||k|cos \phi$$ since k is a unit vector than |k| = 1 and we can then isolate |n| to get
$$|n|=\frac{n\cdot k}{cos\phi}$$
and since $$||ru \times rv|| =  |n|$$ so
$$Area(S)=\int \int_D \frac{n \cdot k\ast dA}{cos\phi}$$
But then I don't how I can remove the n * k.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The element area of the surface dS projects on xOy as $dA = dS \, cos \phi$

with dS the domain is defined on the surface.

with dA the domain is defined in the xOy plane.

example : surface of a half sphere

integration on the sphere : $dS = R d\theta \, R cos\theta\,d\phi$

$S = \int dS = R^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \, cos\theta = 2 \pi R^2$

integration on the xOy plane : $dA = r d\phi \, dr $ and $dA = dS \, cos \theta$ (in this example)

$S = \int dS = \int_0^{R} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \, r/cos \theta $

as $r = R \, cos \theta$ : $S = \int_0^{R} dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \, R = 2\pi R^2 $